# AWS SSL Certificate Error - ELB/Wordpress/Apache2/Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-certificate-manager

I requested a certificate for the site directly from AWS (techruptr.co.uk, *.techruptr.co.uk) and associated with the EIP, created the ELB and ensure they are all linked together.  The site is Wordpress and I've installed Really Simple SSL that confirms the SSL is active.

However, when you go to the site it says it is not secure and that there is an issue with the certificate.   It appears to suggest that I've used a self-signed certificate, but this shouldn't be the case.  There may also be an issue with the common name as it is the amazon assigned name rather than the website name, but doesn't seem to be anywhere to fix this on in the Certificate Manager Console.  Have attached testing results too [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4q2l.png).

Am on the verge of giving up and just importing an SSL certificate from elsewhere but thought I'd ask for help first.

Comment: Is your domain name/DNS managed in route53 or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the SSL certificate generated by the Amazon Certificate Manager service at all. Also you shouldn't be using an Elasitc IP at all if you are using an Elastic Load Balancer.

It appears that you have a self-signed certificate installed on your Wordpress server, an Elastic IP assigned to that server, and your DNS records are pointing directly to that Elastic IP. This configuration would completely bypass the Elastic Load Balancer. Since the ACM certificate is served by the load balancer this is also completely bypassing the ACM certificate.

You need to configure your DNS to point to the Elastic Load Balancer, not the Elastic IP of the EC2 instance, if you want to actually use the ELB and the ACM certificate.

Comment: In our hosted zone, we've got CNAME thats pointed to the load balancer.       We also have a Type A thats pointed towards the IP address of the instance. When this IP address is removed, the Site says "Too many redirects". The load balancer has an instance, so I'm not sure why I'd need to add Type A value off my IP address of the instance.

Comment: Both the CNAME and the A record should point to the load balancer. The too many redirects error means you have your webserver configured incorrectly for running behind a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks - all sorted.  Found the redirect problem too - was pointing at images on the demo site so just needed to reload them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Mark B mentioned you are not all using SSL issued by AWS ACM manager. You need to configure you elastic load balancer end point in you DNS manager. If you still having issues then you can move your DNS zone to Route53 and add hosted zone by A record set.

Comment: In our hosted zone, we've got CNAME thats pointed to the load balancer.       We also have a Type A thats pointed towards the IP address of the instance. When this IP address is removed, the Site says "Too many redirects". The load balancer has an instance, so I'm not sure why I'd need to add Type A value off my IP address of the instance.